# How can my Flask gunicorn app remember its state?

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I am running a python3/flask app on gunicorn in heroku. This app presents the user with a list of items, pulled in from an API call, for the user to accept or reject. Depending on whether the user hits the accept or reject links associated with each item, the app appends the item to either an internal list of accepted items are one of rejected items.

Currently I'm storing each list (suggestions, acceptances and rejections) as a pandas dataframe object within the app.

i.e. I initialise my app with an empty data frame:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.accepted = pd.DataFrame()
app.suggested = pd.DataFrame()
```

populate the suggestions data frame with an API call:

```
@app.route("/get_suggestions")
def get_suggestions():
  app.suggested = <some data returned from an API>
```

then append a suggested item to the accepted dataframe once an 'accept' link is hit:

```
@app.route("/accept/<suggest_id>")
def accept_item(suggest_id):
  app.accepted(len(app.accepted)) = app.suggested.loc[int(suggest_id)]
```

This all works fine running on gunicorn on my local miniconda virtual environment (running "heroku local web") but when deployed on heroku I keep getting "Internal Server Error". When i look at the logs, it looks like the app's internal variables (e.g. app.suggested) are not being preserved, such that when accept_item is run, app.suggested is always empty. Why would they be preserved on the local version but not on the heroku deployment?

What's the simplest way of preserving this state? I'd like a small number of multiple users to be able to use the app and each build their own temporary lists. Do i need to use SQLite to preserve state? Do i need to drop a cookie into the user's browser so i can tell different users apart? I'd prefer not to require users to create an account on my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

- Either save this state into cookies (which I would not recommend), or
- Store this data into a database like [Heroku Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/postgres) (for instance), and use SQLAlchemy or some other ORM to retrieve and store that data.

Heroku dynos (which run your web application) are stateless. They reboot at will, don't persist disk, etc.

Storing global state won't work because those variables you're defining are changing on every incoming request.

You could use the [app context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/appcontext/) to store this state, but since you're running on Heroku this is asking for trouble since the dynos will restart at random.